# using the .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have written the following line of code in the .htaccess file..

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L] 

RewriteRule ^honeymoon$ honeymoon.php [L]
```

to redirect http://localhost/site1/honeymoon.php to http://localhost/site1/honeymoon/

but am getting the error message from my browser..

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16
```

What is the problem. Please some one help me.

Comment: I think that issue with your code not with the .htaccess , can you check that without htaccess it would work with simple URL : `http://localhost/site1/honeymoon.php`?

Comment: make sure you are writing in root .htaccess file not inner .htaccess...

Comment: try with http://localhost/site1/honeymoon last slash (/) can cause this problem.

Comment: Where is your htaccess currently located (in which folder) ?

Comment: `Please some one help me.` If you're not going to respond to people's inquiries (the comments above), I don't see how anyone can help you.